# Is it possible to efficiently implement Lamping's abstract algorithm on interaction combinators?

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

There is a known implementation of [λ-calculus terms on interaction nets](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/projects/xslam/wolam1/Mackie-Pinto.ps). It is, though, overly complex and inefficient. It is known that Lamping's abstract algorithm is capable of evaluating a very huge subset of λ-calculus terms to normal form optimally. Moreover, it is remarkably similar to interaction combinators, with only one key difference: instead of 2 types of nodes, there is an infinite family of different possible nodes. In other words, Lamping's abstract algorithm is just interaction combinators plus integer labels.

Is it possible to simulate those integer labels (and, thus, the abstract algorithm) efficiently on interaction combinators?